# Illegal access error when deleting Google Pub Sub subscription upon JVM shutdown

Tags: scala, tomcat, jvm, google-cloud-pubsub, shutdown-hook

I'm trying to delete a Google Pub Sub subscription in a JVM shutdown hook, but I'm encountering an illegal access error with the Google Pub Sub subscription admin client when the shutdown hook runs. I've tried using both `sys.addShutdownHook` as well as `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook`, but I get the same error either way.

```
val deleteInstanceCacheSubscriptionThread = new Thread {
  override def run: Unit = {
     cacheUpdateService. deleteInstanceCacheUpdateSubscription()
  }
}
sys.addShutdownHook(deleteInstanceCacheSubscriptionThread.run)
// Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(deleteInstanceCacheSubscriptionThread)
```

This is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "shutdownHook1" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [META-INF/services/com.google.auth.http.HttpTransportFactory]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1385)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResources(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:985)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResources(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1086)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:348)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:393)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:474)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators.getNext(Iterators.java:845)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterables.getFirst(Iterables.java:779)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getFromServiceLoader(OAuth2Credentials.java:318)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.<init>(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:145)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.createScoped(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:505)
    at com.google.api.gax.core.GoogleCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(GoogleCredentialsProvider.java:92)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:142)
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.stub.GrpcSubscriberStub.create(GrpcSubscriberStub.java:263)
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.stub.SubscriberStubSettings.createStub(SubscriberStubSettings.java:242)
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.SubscriptionAdminClient.<init>(SubscriptionAdminClient.java:178)
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.SubscriptionAdminClient.create(SubscriptionAdminClient.java:159)
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.SubscriptionAdminClient.create(SubscriptionAdminClient.java:150)
    at com.company.pubsub.services.GooglePubSubService.$anonfun$deleteSubscription$2(GooglePubSubService.scala:384)
    at com.company.utils.TryWithResources$.withResources(TryWithResources.scala:21)
    at com.company.pubsub.services.GooglePubSubService.$anonfun$deleteSubscription$1(GooglePubSubService.scala:384)
    at com.company.scalalogging.Logging.time(Logging.scala:43)
    at com.company.scalalogging.Logging.time$(Logging.scala:35)
    at com.company.pubsub.services.GooglePubSubService.time(GooglePubSubService.scala:30)
    at com.company.pubsub.services.GooglePubSubService.deleteSubscription(GooglePubSubService.scala:382)
    at com.company.cache.services.CacheUpdateService.deleteInstanceCacheUpdateSubscription(CacheUpdateService.scala:109)
    at com.company.cache.services.CacheUpdateHandlerService$$anon$1.run(CacheUpdateHandlerService.scala:132)
    at com.company.cache.services.CacheUpdateHandlerService$.$anonfun$addSubscriptionShutdownHook$1(CacheUpdateHandlerService.scala:135)
    at scala.sys.ShutdownHookThread$$anon$1.run(ShutdownHookThread.scala:37)
```

It seems like by the time the shutdown hook runs the Pub Sub library has already shut down, so we can't access the subscription admin client anymore. But, I was wondering if there was anyway to delete the subscription before this happens.